# Android slow custom layout

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have the following problem: I want to show dialog fragment which background will be custom layout. But in constructor of this custom layout I inflate xml layout and after that I programatically add views (according to the data in the constructor). So there is allocations in the constructor and it is super slow. Even if I try to animate the button which open the dialog, the animation of the button is laggy (it shows in 4-5 frames ). So obviously it is not a good practice to allocate and add so many objects in the constructor of this custom layout, but how can I avoid this? I want to add views according to the data, because of that I cannot add them all in the layout that I inflate. I cannot copy code, because it is work related.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post some code?

Comment: We won't be able to help you much without seeing your code

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `RecyclerLayout` or `ListView` to populate your dynamic elements. It takes time when you have a lot of views to be added dynamically to UI view.

Hope it will help.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't find anything about RecyclerLayout. ListView is useless in my case. I will try to put all views in xml, but I don't think this will help.

Comment: What type of view are you trying to add? You can add any type of view in listView but you need to be little bit tricky.

Comment: I Inflate FrameLayout and inside it there is 15 views ( I add all of them margins, because they should be to specific places on this view). So I don't know how to use ListView. But it is still weird for me, why when I press the button for opening the dialog why the button's animation lag ? I inflate ImageView for background and 15 more RelativeLayouts, I add 1 or 2 ImageViews in every one , then set imageresource to them and I create and start animations for all ImageViews. I know that this is not soft work, but it's weird that the animation lag. It's very ugly. 
Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Are you familiar with listView? and which button animation you are talking about, button that is used to open dialog or the buttons those are in dialog?

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with ListView. I talk about animation used to open the dialog.

Comment: You mean dialog animation?

Comment: Sorry, I mean animation on button that is used to open the dialog. I want to shake the button (this animation lag).

Comment: Ok, where are you processing the data that you are going to display?

Comment: Which dialog are you using? AlertDialog or DialogFragment.

Comment: I use DialogFragment. I pass the data throught the Dialogfragment constructor, after that I start to add views and start animations (all of this in the constructor). 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think you are adding views in onCreate() callback. Do that in onViewCreated() callback you animation problem should be solved.

Comment: I was adding everything in the constructor.

Comment: Adding any initialization in the contractor of fragment is a bad practice. So do that is onCreateView so   it will not affect you animation.

Comment: I mean that the constructor of the custom layout is executed in onCreateView method of the fragment.
Actually I try to make simple dialog fragment and if I start animation inside it is lagging. I just add background and ImageButton and try to animation the button and the the animation is not flowing ( you can see only 5-6 framed maximum). When I make it in another project (with the same styles) there is no lag and the animation working perfect (I try with objectAnimator and from xml - the same result).  It is not from animation.
It is something from application, but I don't know what.
Thanks.

Comment: In the comment above I mean I try to animate a button inside dialog fragment ! And it's awfull

Comment: For posting the code - @chandil03, unfortunatelly I can't, because it's work related.